# Error while installing react in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an error while installing react on my laptop. As I opened Visual Studio Code and used `npx create-react-app project`, I get this error:

> Errors are like: no matching version found for @babel/helper-plugin-utils@^7.21.5

Rectify my problem for complete process of installing React in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I suggest you trying again, maybe something went wrong on the first try.

Comment: Check registry value if its different set it to `registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/`
using set this `npm config set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ `and `install npm`

Comment: Your `npm` version might be outdated. In that case run `npm update`.